# TypeError: sentimentCurrent.map is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Trying to write a unit test for the below function.

I'm getting an error of

```
TypeError: sentimentCurrent.map is not a function

      65 |     console.log("sentimentData:",sentimentCurrent,typeof sentimentCurrent);
      66 | 
    > 67 |     sentimentCurrent.map(function (k, num) {
         |                      ^
      68 |       let dateCreated = new Date(k.created * 1000);
      69 | 
      70 |       DataInput.push({
```

The actual function is below, it takes in raw data and then prepares it to be used in a linegraph essentially.

```
    export default function generateLineGraphPointsSentiment(
  sentimentData
) {
  
  if (sentimentData !=null) {
  const DataInput = [];

  Object.keys(sentimentData).map(function (key, item) {
    var sentimentCurrent = sentimentData[key];
    sentimentCurrent.map(function (k, num) {
      let dateCreated = new Date(k.created * 1000);

      DataInput.push({
        created: dateCreated,
        sentiment: k.sentiment,
        magnitude: k.magnitude,
        date: k.createdDay,
      });
    });

    // {created: 1601820360, sentiment: -0.1, magnitude: 0.1, createdDay: "2020-10-05"}
  });

  

  return DataInput
}
else { return 0 }
}
```

The test case is as follows,

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import generateLineGraphPointsSentiment from './generateGraphPointsAnalysis';

    const ExpressionData = [
  {
    "2021-08-21": [
        {
            "id": 96451,
            "user_id": "xxxx",
            "sentiment": 0.4,
            "magnitude": 1,
            "created": 1629535058,
            "createdDay": "2021-08-21"
        },
        {
            "id": 96452,
            "user_id": "xxx",
            "sentiment": -0.1,
            "magnitude": 1,
            "created": 1629535060,
            "createdDay": "2021-08-21"
        },
        
    ]
}

// const setSelectedDate = jest.fn();

describe('Generates Graph Points Sentiment', () => {
  it('should show loader for the LineGraphs graph if no data is present', () => {
    generateSentimentLineGraph = generateLineGraphPointsSentiment(SentimentData);
    console.log(generateSentimentLineGraph,SentimentData,typeof SentimentData);

    expect(generateSentimentLineGraph).toHaveReturned();
  });
});
```

Any ideas on what is wrong with my code? It works in dev currently, not sure why it's failing this test now? I think it has something to do with either the type of data being processed, or how I'm using the map functions. Perhaps I can simplify the first map function?

#### Updated test data to duplicate what is going in at start, and the after the first map data is like this,

```
[
    {
        "id": 96451,
        "user_id": "xxx",
        "sentiment": 0.4,
        "magnitude": 1,
        "created": 1629535058,
        "createdDay": "2021-08-21"
    },
    {
        "id": 96452,
        "user_id": "xxx",
        "sentiment": -0.1,
        "magnitude": 1,
        "created": 1629535060,
        "createdDay": "2021-08-21"
    },
]
```

Keeping in mind this currently works when used in the line graph, which is like this from ReCharts library,

```
<LineChart
        width={550}
        height={250}
        data={Sentiment}
        syncId="anyId"
        margin={{
          top: 10,
          right: 30,
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0,
        }}
      >
```

#### Great answers, works for the test now, but in loading in the dev environment I get this error weirdly,

[image]

Comment: `sentimentCurrent` is an object... one of the elements from the `SentimentData` array. I don't see a `map` property on it that is a function, so the error tracks.

Comment: When it's failing like this, what are the console log outputs for `sentimentData`? Seems like it's not an array when running in your dev env.

Answer (score 1):

If functionality works fine - I assume that the problem is with your `const SentimentData`.

Because from the looks of it, `Object.keys(sentimentData)` expects `sentimentData` to be a "proper" object, like `{key: "bla"}`. Instead, you're giving it an array, which technically still is an object, so for an array of two elements, you'll get two keys: `["0", "1"]`.

And then you do `sentimentCurrent = sentimentData[key];` which is same as `sentimentCurrent = sentimentData["0"];` which just retuns first, or second object from the array.

And then you're trying to run `Array.map()` function on an object which doesn't make sense.

So, my advice, if functionality works as expected, try logging your `sentimentData` and update mocked data in the test accordingly.

This should work:

```js
function generateLineGraphPointsSentiment(sentimentData) {
  if (sentimentData != null) {
    const DataInput = [];

    Object.keys(sentimentData).map(function (key, item) {
      var sentimentCurrent = sentimentData[key];

      sentimentCurrent.map(function (k, num) {
        let dateCreated = new Date(k.created * 1000);

        DataInput.push({
          created: dateCreated,
          sentiment: k.sentiment,
          magnitude: k.magnitude,
          date: k.createdDay,
        });
      });

      // {created: 1601820360, sentiment: -0.1, magnitude: 0.1, createdDay: "2020-10-05"}
    });

    return DataInput;
  }
}

const SentimentData = {
  "2021-08-21": [
    {
      id: 96451,
      user_id: "xxxx",
      sentiment: 0.4,
      magnitude: 1,
      created: 1629535058,
      createdDay: "2021-08-21",
    },
    {
      id: 96452,
      user_id: "xxx",
      sentiment: -0.1,
      magnitude: 1,
      created: 1629535060,
      createdDay: "2021-08-21",
    },
  ],
};

const generateSentimentLineGraph = generateLineGraphPointsSentiment(SentimentData);

console.log(generateSentimentLineGraph);
```

Comment: I'm confused why it actually works generally thoguh!

Comment: I believe that my answer is pretty clear, not sure what to add. Your `ExpressionData` seems to be kinda correct now and should eliminate the original issue.

Comment: also, don't use `toHaveReturned`, it seems to be only working for mocks, but you're testing actual function

Comment: see updated answer, may help

Answer (score 1):

`sentimentCurrent` is an object... one of the elements from the `SentimentData` array. I don't see a `map` property on it that is a function, so the error tracks.

From what I can see it looks like you are trying to map the passed `sentimentData` array into `DataInput` where you've augmented/updated the `created` property.

```
const SentimentData = [
  {
    id: 96452,
    user_id: 'asdasd',
    sentiment: -0.1,
    magnitude: 1,
    created: 1629535060,
    createdDay: '2021-08-21',
  },
  {
    id: 96453,
    user_id: 'asdasd',
    sentiment: 1,
    magnitude: 1,
    created: 1629535063,
    createdDay: '2021-08-21',
  },
];
```

...

```
export default function generateLineGraphPointsSentiment(sentimentData) {
  console.log("sentimentData:", sentimentData, typeof sentimentData);
  if (sentimentData !=null) {
    const DataInput = sentimentData.map(item => {
      const dateCreated = new Date(item.created * 1000);

      return {
        created: dateCreated,
        sentiment: item.sentiment,
        magnitude: item.magnitude,
        date: item.createdDay,
      }
    });

    // {created: 1601820360, sentiment: -0.1, magnitude: 0.1, createdDay: "2020-10-05"}

  ...
```

### Update

You seem to have changed the data that is supposedly sent to `generateLineGraphPointsSentiment`. This is an array of objects with a single key and array of objects.

```
const ExpressionData = [
  {
    "2021-08-21": [
      {
        id: 96451,
        user_id: "xxxx",
        sentiment: 0.4,
        magnitude: 1,
        created: 1629535058,
        createdDay: "2021-08-21"
      },
      {
        id: 96452,
        user_id: "xxx",
        sentiment: -0.1,
        magnitude: 1,
        created: 1629535060,
        createdDay: "2021-08-21"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Map over the outer array, then map over the inner object values array to map these elements to the `DataInput` element objects you want. Flatten all the arrays down.

```
export default function generateLineGraphPointsSentiment(sentimentData) {
  console.log("sentimentData:", sentimentData, typeof sentimentData);
  if (sentimentData !=null) {
    const DataInput = sentimentData.flatMap((el) => {
      return Object.values(el).flatMap((values) => {
        return values.map((item) => {
          const dateCreated = new Date(item.created * 1000);

          return {
            created: dateCreated,
            sentiment: item.sentiment,
            magnitude: item.magnitude,
            date: item.createdDay
          };
        });
      });
    });

    // {created: 1601820360, sentiment: -0.1, magnitude: 0.1, createdDay: "2020-10-05"}

  ...
```

```js
const ExpressionData = [
  {
    "2021-08-21": [
      {
        id: 96451,
        user_id: "xxxx",
        sentiment: 0.4,
        magnitude: 1,
        created: 1629535058,
        createdDay: "2021-08-21"
      },
      {
        id: 96452,
        user_id: "xxx",
        sentiment: -0.1,
        magnitude: 1,
        created: 1629535060,
        createdDay: "2021-08-21"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const DataInput = ExpressionData.flatMap((el) => {
  return Object.values(el).flatMap((values) => {
    return values.map((item) => {
      const dateCreated = new Date(item.created * 1000);

      return {
        created: dateCreated,
        sentiment: item.sentiment,
        magnitude: item.magnitude,
        date: item.createdDay
      };
    });
  });
});

console.log(DataInput);
```

Comment: unfortunately I receive a new error when using the function in my react class to pass data to the linegraph,

Comment: @LeCoda And what is this new error?

Comment: Same error basically!

Comment: I see.... you may be mutating the `sentimentData` value somewhere into something the code is not expecting. Do you have complete code examples to provide us?

Comment: That's basically it, the graph is from ReCharts https://recharts.org/ , no other data manipulation occurs outside of what's their in, middle and out (weirdly comes out fine in code but not in tests)

Comment: @LeCoda You changed the code in your question. Are you passing `ExpressionData` (*array of objects with array values*) instead now?

Comment: yes I am, made a mistake, apologies

Comment: @LeCoda No worries, it happens. Please check my answer update.

Comment: Man thanks so much. Saddly it works in test case but in dev environment i has a new bug. So weird!

Comment: @LeCoda Are you *sure* the data is the same in both places you are running/testing the code? What is the error/bug now in the dev environment?

Comment: put it above, yeah it's really odd!

Answer (score 1):

The parameter that you pass in the test case. you should use ExpressionData replace SentimentData. you should modify your code like this, 'generateLineGraphPointsSentiment(ExpressionData);'